# Find large video files inside sub folders and compress them inside the folder

Tags: linux, find, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I want to find all the video files larger than some specific size and compress them and save them in the same directory where it present.

Comment: Video files aren't usually compressible. You'll get a better reduction in size by re-encoding at a lower resolution or frame rate - but obviously that's very lossy

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -type f -size +495M -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -vcodec libx265 -crf 20 "${file%.mp4}_low.mp4"  < /dev/null
done
```

Replace **+495M** with the number according to your needs. At present it finds files larger than 495MB and reduces their size using ffmpeg.